# How can one import the contents of a file that is stored in SharePoint into an MS Word file using VBA?

Tags: vba, sharepoint, ms-word

I have the following use case.

I have a document that has a "Terms and Conditions" H1 section. There is no content in that section.

The content of this section is in different files (depending on the region for which the T&Cs need to be incorporated) on SharePoint. For example, the T&C for America is in a different file, and the T&C for Canada is in a different file--all on SharePoint.

I want to have a functionality where the user can select the region (using a checkbox field in user form) for which they want to plug in the T&C. And then the content of the file, which is on SharePoint is pasted in the Terms and Conditions section.

How can i please accomplish this using VBA. Can you please break it down for me.

Comment: `myRange.InsertFile "https://blah.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/TestLibrary/Document.docx"` where `myRange` is where you want to insert the content.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a bookmark (eg "TandC") in your document then you can do this:

```
Dim url as String 

'Assign a url based on the user's selection...
url = "https://blah.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/TestLibrary/TandC_USA.docx" 'for example

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TandC").Range.InsertFile url
```

Instead of having one document each with a separate T&C, you could combine all of the T&C in the same document, and give each one a distinct bookmark, then provide that bookmark name when calling InsertFile:

`ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TandC").Range.InsertFile url, "TandC_USA"`

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.insertfile

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a functionality where the user can select the region for which they want to plug in the T&C. And then the content of the file, which is on SharePoint is pasted in the Terms and Conditions section.

And how do you want to implement the facility? **Content Controls, Active X Controls, User Form**, etc.?

Then you must have full permission to read and download the complete file.

The body of the functionality of yours may be like this :

```vb
Rem creedit with YouChat:
Sub ImportSharePointFile()

    ' Defined variables
    Dim SPFileUrl As String  ' SharePoint file's URL '
    Dim SPFileName As String ' File name of the SharePoint file
    
    Dim HttpReq As Object       ' Http request object
    Dim Stream As Object        ' ADODB Stream object
    Dim TempFilePath As String  ' Temporary file path
    
    Dim Doc As Document         ' Word Document object
    
    Dim rngToInsert As Range
        
    ' set the SharePoint file's URL and it's name
    SPFileUrl = "https://...."
    SPFileName = ".... yourfile.docx"
    
   ' Send Http request to download SharePoint files to local
    Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    HttpReq.Open "GET", SPFileUrl, False
    HttpReq.send
    
    If HttpReq.Status = 200 Then ' Http request success
    
        ' Create a temporary file
        TempFilePath = VBA.Environ$("temp") & "\" & SPFileName
        Set Stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 1 ' Binary Types
        Stream.Open
        Stream.Write HttpReq.responseBody ' Write the contents of the Http request to Stream
        Stream.SaveToFile TempFilePath, 2 ' Write the contents of the Stream to a file
        Stream.Close
        Set Stream = Nothing
        
        ' Insert the contents of the temporary file into a Word document
        Set Doc = ActiveDocument ' Assuming that the current document is a Word document that needs to be imported
         'insert into the specific position
        Set rngToInsert = Doc.Sections("Terms and Conditions").Range
        rngToInsert.InsertFile TempFilePath
        
        ' Delete the temporary file
        Kill TempFilePath
    
    End If
    
    ' Released Objects
    Set HttpReq = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: So is YouChat like ChatGPT then?

Comment: @braX Yes, see  <https://you.com/>

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me update my question with how i wish to implement the functionality.

Comment: @Nosail You can try to load it with my code above, just specify the **URL** and **file name** of the file you want to insert. Because I can download it when I test it, but the downloaded or obtained file is not complete, there will be an error when inserting it. I'm not sure if it's a problem with my permissions or the code suggested by *YouChat*. If the code I gave you above really works for you (at least to download the complete file) then I am willing to try to implement the mechanism of selecting which file to download to insert into the Word file according to your needs.

Comment: "ChatGPT"-generated answers are currently banned on SO

Comment: @TimWilliams So I can't refer to those? or I can't talk about where they come from? Of course, I wrote it out just after I have tested it myself. Should even the part I wrote myself to be denied? Just because I confess where the reference comes from? After that, don’t say it out, it’s fine. is that so? Please be more respectful and rigorous when making such evaluations or judgments. okay?

Comment: Since you referenced having used a generative AI for the code and added the credit to your code, I was only pointing out the policy (partly to give you a heads-up in case someone else might decide to remove it). It's not a question of "respect" so I'm not sure why you jumped to that from what I wrote.

Comment: @TimWilliams I had been hesitant to write it out, but now it's good that I don't have to confess in the future anyway. Maybe not you, but it just so happens that I saw that I was voted down once again, just to take advantage of the opportunity to announce. It wasn't against you, this was for the people who came after me. Probably no one will ever again be unpleasant to themselves. In fact, to put it bluntly, is to have their own things, before they dare to note out. The real only follows the generative AI and foxes fake tiger, who I think will never reveal their own bottom.

Comment: @TimWilliams btw "cre-edit" not "credit" is the term I created myself to combine create and edit into one to express co-workly to editing.

Comment: IA-generated posts/answers are a touchy subject here (BTW it was not my downvote) but I think lots of folks rightly feel we should discourage use of AI for writing answers - otherwise the end result will be lots of questions based around "I used ChatGPT to write this code but it doesn't do what I need - can you please fix it for me?" and similarly a huge number of auto-generated answers produced by the same tech.  At that point the usefulness of SO is pretty much dead, and I for one would likely be done with it.

Comment: @jonsson it's OK, voters and be-voted have their freedom, I WILL NOT MENTION WHERE I GOT AND HOW HE HELPS ME, ON THIS SITE ANYMORE. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks @OscarSun I will check the code and revert.

Comment: Hi @OscarSun i ran the code, but i don't see the contents of the file. I just see some boilerplate SharePoint OneDrive content: https://imgur.com/a/znaE9hO

The content in the file is formatted text in two columns that i want to be pasted in my document.

Comment: @Nosail Have you opened the downloaded file in the download location/path to see it? If it's not what you expect, I don't know, so you'll have to ask someone else to help you out. If you can't open it and there is an error, then it is the same as mine, maybe it is a permission problem to download the complete file, or the code given by *YouChat* is problematic, just for reference, or a fake, not practical enough. My current capability is that I can only insert the desired file into the destination file after it has been downloaded successfully.

Comment: @Nosail Try asking the seniors who participated in the discussion of this post, maybe they will have a solution.

Comment: @OscarSun i can both download and open the file from the SharePoint path that i have specified.

Comment: @Nosail Are you sure the file you downloaded is the one to insert to the dest. ? If that content is correct then we can step to the next. *using a checkbox field in user form* so you want a user form? And checkboxes, not combo boxs or list boxs? Can you do it yourself and give that sample to me, I'll implement the code in it then.

Comment: I can both download and view the file using the link, but when i add it in code, the content that shows up is different as highlighted in imgur.com/a/znaE9hO.

And yes, I will put together a form and share it with you.

Comment: @Nosail If the content you downloaded with this code is different from the original file you stored on SharePoint, it means that the code is not working as expected, do you still want to insert them into your target file? Wouldn't you want to wait for a better download code?

Comment: oh yes, i would like to wait for code that works, @OscarSun. Would you be able to help me?

Comment: @Nosail Sorry, cause I don't have the SharePoint environment to test, I only have the account that my alma mater gave, and without administrator Privileges, there is nothing I can do to help.  Did Tim Williams's answer not help?